# Using WGET with cloud hosted generic FTP URL

Tags: ftp, wget, directory-listing

I'm trying to use WGET to download a website which is hosted on a Netregistry cloud. WGET fails with

```
--> LIST -a
150 Here comes the directory listing.
(skipping "LIST")done.
ftp.netregistry.net: Permission deniedftp.netregistry.net/.listing: No such file or directory
```

I suspect the problem arises because the FTP login is a generic URL (ftp.netregistry.net) and the home directory is set by my username. So the listing file is really in some deeper location, perhaps. There is no more specific URL available. WGET's PWD gives a result of "/" (in debug mode).

Is this likely to be the problem, and if so is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Aaah - silly question! I was under the entirely mistaken impression that the .listing file was being created on the remote system. In fact it is created on the *local* system, and my problem was simply one of local permissions.

In my defence, WGET's error message could perhaps be a bit more explicit, by giving the full path of the offending file; the partial path given looks just like the remote path, not the local path.

Thanks for your time if you read this!